# Fuzzy not working for lead company name

Tags: duplicate-management, duplicate-value

I created a matching rule and duplicate rule regarding lead company name and i tested by creating records with company name as test and test data The record is saving without showing any duplicates found.
For reference please find  below screenshots .Is there any other way to achieve this.
[image: Matching Rule Detail Screenshot]

[image: Duplicate Rule Detail Screenshot]

```
Trigger DuplicateLeadPreventer on Lead
                              (before insert, before update) {
                                                               
//Since only certain leads will match, put them in a separate list
List<Lead> LeadstoProcess = new List<Lead> ();

//Company to Lead Map
Map<String, Lead> leadMap = new Map<String, Lead>();
                                 
                                 

   for (Lead lead : Trigger.new) {

    //Only process for Leads in our RecordTypeMap
     

       // Make sure we don't treat an Company name that
      // isn't changing during an update as a duplicate.

             if (
                (lead.company != null) &&
                (Trigger.isInsert ||
                (lead.company != Trigger.oldMap.get(lead.Id).company))
                )
                {

                   // Make sure another new lead isn't also a duplicate

                       if (leadMap.containsKey(lead.company)) {
                           lead.company.addError('Another new lead has the '
                                           + 'same company name.');
                       } else {
                           leadMap.put(lead.company , lead);
                           LeadstoProcess.add(lead);
                       
               }
   } //end RT If Check
   } //End Loop

   /*
    Using a single database query, find all the leads in
    the database that have the same company address as any
    of the leads being inserted or updated.

  */

   Set<String> ExistingCompanies = new Set<String> ();

           for (Lead l: [Select Id, Company from Lead WHERE Company IN :leadMap.keyset()]) {
                         ExistingCompanies.add(l.Company);
               }

   //Now loop through leads to process, since we should only loop if matches
  /* for (Lead l : LeadstoProcess) {
       if (ExistingCompanies.contains(l.company) ) {
            l.company.addError('A lead with this company '
                              + 'name already exists.');
       } */
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the word "data" would be stripped for the sake of fuzzy matching in a company name, as that would likely be a definitive word in the name. For instance you probably would not want a match between "Data Pros" and "The Pros, Inc." ("the" and "inc." would be removed in fuzzy) in a live scenario. What are some real use cases you are trying to capture?

You can see some basic description behind SF fuzzy matching logic here:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=matching_rules_matching_methods.htm&type=5

Specifically, on fuzzy matching for company name:

> Removes words such as “Inc” and “Corp” before comparing fields. Also,
>   company names are normalized. For example, “IBM” is normalized to
>   “International Business Machines”.

Comment: The leads must allow duplicates company ,it must display the duplicate records and save the record.Client has 10,000 leads at present they need to see the duplicates using fuzzy .

Comment: I already raised ticket to Salesforce Team they suggested not to use fuzzy .They explained that there  are some bugs regarding fuzzy .They ask me to upvote the idea to implement.Can you help me how can we acheive this issue by Customization whether we need to implement aura components or trigger etc.

Comment: Sure, can you elaborate on how your matching criteria should work? More examples of should-be matches would help too.

Comment: Company name must allow duplicates with fuzzy logic for Example :If Company name is Krishna Pipes for one record and other record name as krishna it must show duplicates and save the record.Indirectly in a new record company name contains any old record company name means it must show duplicates and save the record.

Comment: I tried by creating trigger but the thing is if i giving any company name its showing duplicates and saving the record can you review the above code.

Comment: I think at this point some use case details will really help. Can you describe the high level problem you are trying to solve (beyond the description of how the logic should work)? In other words, what is the core business problem that this architecture is designed to solve?

Comment: our client has 3-4 customers with 10,000 leads at present.They want to allow duplicates.Suppose Cafe Coffe Day has multiple branches .It must allow branches wise some code with name .